# How to do REST API Call from a Salesforce Commerce Cloud Store Front Page?

Tags: salesforce-commerce-cloud

I am new to Salesforce Commerce Cloud(SFCC). I would like to do REST API call to an external system when a storefront page's button is being clicked. What are the available ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no extra requirements for it. You can consume a REST API via javascript. Or you can use the Service framework on the backend side.